# How to add Query in Submitting Button and find value in another table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

After I input the code then click the submit , It will find in the database into member if the code (example 0000556397) is correct , if it's correct in attendance table it will shows the information of who submit their code but if it's not it will pop up a no user found

```
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">&nbsp;ID:</label>
        <div class="reason">
            <input type="text" class="span2.5" id="inputEmail" name="rfid"  placeholder="Tap your I.D">
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-save icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use something like AJAX for this.

Comment: i dont know how to use it just using php and html btw i'm using phpymadmin and wamp for my localhost ty

Comment: On button click, make an ajax call to a php file and post the code from input the form. In the php file, check if the code is there, if so, query the db with it - if no value is returned use that and create the popup saying no data was found.if data is found, create some ouput html with it, and add that to your page content. Try to read the right answer of the duplicated question that mplungjan marked, and you will find your solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!